# Unable to create a Maven application with Vaadin in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to create a Vaadin application in Eclipse using Maven and am unable to do so. The official instructions (https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20an%20Eclipse%20Project) say to create a new Maven project in Eclipse and ""vaadin-archetype-application" in the list of archetypes. I can't see anything of such kind. Then, I added an archetype and gave the following details:

```
Archetype Group ID: com.vaadin
Archetype Artifact ID: vaadin-archetype-application
Archetype Version: 7.1.7
```

Even this didn't work and I keep getting the error, `Could not resolve artifact`.

Please help!

I am on Eclipse Kepler IDE for Java EE Developers and have the Vaadin Plugin for Eclipse installed. Maven Integration for Eclipse was already installed in this bundle.

**UPDATE:** I also tried these settings but to no avail

```
Archetype Group ID: com.vaadin
Archetype Artifact ID: vaadin-archetype-clean
Archetype Version: LATEST
```

Comment: Do you have a custom Maven configuration or are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: Oh yes, I am behind a proxy. But, eclipse works fine behind this proxy. I mean it updates and even this Vaadin plugin I installed behind this proxy only

Comment: Did you also configure Maven to use a proxy? Open `settings.xml` and verify if there's a proxy configured.

Comment: There is no settings.xml in the .m2 folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: Right, so I created one and gave my settings. works now! Could you add it as an answer?

Comment: Done, if you use an external Maven installation you could also find a `settings.xml` in your `conf` directory of that installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This artifact could be found inside the central Maven repository. If you can't find it there it could be because you disabled looking up there, or you're unable to look it up due to network errors.

Verify if there are any specific changes at `settings.xml` and if you're behind a proxy or something. If you're behind a proxy, you need to configure a proxy in your Maven `settings.xml`, for example:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>myproxy.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>passw0rd</password>
        <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

The `settings.xml` file can be found at the `conf` directory of your Maven installation or you could define it in your global Maven settings in the `.m2` folder.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I am getting another error. ArtifactTransferException. Any idea as to what this is?

Comment: Maybe your local repo became "corrupt" because of the proxy. Try removing the folders in your `.m2` folder that contain the artifact you need.